# Merging sda2 and sda5 with LVM via SSH

Tags: partitioning, ssh, lvm

I was trying to find answers here but wasn't having much luck, so here goes:

I access a server via SSH and the current partitions are as follows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x691c5ec5

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     782335     780288   381M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           784382 1953523711 1952739330 931.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5           784384 1903982591 1903198208 907.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1903984640 1953523711   49539072  23.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000203804160 bytes, 1953523055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa2dc3d91
```

LVM is installed and working. <strike>sda1 is my current installation of Ubuntu 16. I can see that sda2 and sda5 are adjacent and I would like to just merge the two partitions if possible. What would be the commands I need to type?</strike>

I see the error of my ways now thanks to the comments. What I  *really* meant to ask was How can I allow my current installation to see and use all of /dev/sdb. The server has 2x 1TB disks and I'm only seeing one of them in my current installation.

Just wanted some guidance so I could be 100% sure the commands are right and so I don't have to spend time reinstalling anything.

Thanks for the help and sorry if this gets asked 100 times daily.

Comment: You can not convert to lvm creating pv and lv is destructive.

Comment: sda1 looks far to small to contain your Ubuntu.  Use `df -h`, `mount` or another command to see what is mounted; but I bet sda5 is Ubuntu, sda1 maybe a /boot partition. Also 'Linux LVM' means you are using LVM, however I see only 'Linux' for SDA5; so you'd have to reformat (destructive) to use LVM   (sda2 is extended; a logical partition & can't contain data - it's data is in sda5 & sda6)

Comment: See https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-converting-an-existing-root-filesystem-to-lvm-partition/amp/ .there is nothing specific to rhel or centos in the convetsion

Comment: Just to reiterate what @guiverc said above, `sda2` and `sda5` are **not** *"adjacent"* - `sda2` is an extended partition that **contains** `sda5` (plus the swap partition `sda6`) - see for example [Partitioning -
 Master Boot Record](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning#Master_Boot_Record_.28partition_table.29)